# How to read function expression syntax in javascript?

Tags: javascript, function, expression

```
function [name]([param1[, param2[, ..., paramN]]]) {
  statements
}
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/function

I am confused what and how to read the above function input values, it is a infinite params input, but don't understand the used of brackets[], why put those.

Comment: The `[]` mean those parameters are optional, meaning you do not have to pass those when calling the function

Comment: In the case of a dynamic language syntax like JavaScript, and in this document [] with a literal inside is a named token.   [name] corresponds to the optional functionName token, as @vanowm poined out creates an anoymous unnamed function.   [param1] corresponds to the first function formal parameter.  These are names for the interpreter to consume and check for syntax correctness.

Answer (score 2):

Square brackets represent `optional`

So it means, that `[name]` is optional, function declared without name become an anonymous function.
`[param1[, param2[,...` this means that the parameters are optional, however because they are shown inside previous parameter (all closing `]` brackets are at the end of the list) means that you can't have `param2`, without `param1`, or `param3` without `param2` and `param1` and so on.

Comment: very uncanny way to say param2 should be there after param1. [param1[, param2[, ..., paramN]]]

Comment: always thought that this has some special meaning, but never found out that practically. Now I know, they played extra safe while writing documentation.

Comment: I found it very easy to follow and understand, unlike API written by google...